# Receive URL in Ionic for ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework. I'm trying to set up a way to receive a url from another app. Like, you are in browser, click share, and send the link to another app (my app). I found this [cordova](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent) plugin, and have integrated it in my app. But this is pulgin for **Android**. I need same functionality in IOS.

Any idea which plugin i need to use for ios.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [Custom URL Scheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) plugin.

> This plugin allows you to start your app by calling it with a URL like mycoolapp://path?foo=bar

Maybe this [article](https://medium.com/angularjs-articles/deep-linking-in-ionic-mobile-applications-44d8b4685bb3) is also in your interest (about deeplinking an Ionic with a Ionic app).

Comment: i already tried this plugin. when i am on safri browser and click share, unable to see my app name ? any sugeestion for the same

Comment: Now I understand. The plugin I suggested enables you to have a custom URL scheme bound to your app. But you look for a solution for Android/IOS where your app is added to the standard social share buttons. I am not familiar with any IOS solution for that. I am sorry.